# Как получить и обработать строку в функции модуля Python?

Tags: c++, python, python-3.x, строки, python-c-api

Нужно писать модуль для python на c++. Хочу передать из пайтона в функцию строковый аргумент, как-то изменить ее, например добавив "!", и вернуть обратно измененную строку. Находил функцию `PyString_AsString`, которая в 3 пайтоне исчезла и появилась куча функций PyUnicode API. Как им воспользоваться?

```
PyObject* get_and_send_string(PyObject *, PyObject* o) {
    char * magicstring = Искомая_функция();
    /*Какие-то возможные операции со строкой
    ...
    ...*/

    PyObject *outString = Py_BuildValue("s", magicstring);
    return outString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* magicstring;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(o, "s",  &magicstring)) {
    return NULL;
}
```

[Соответствующий раздел документации.](http://Parsing%20arguments%20and%20building%20values)